I want to ask about echart's magic type. Isn't there a way to change the chart other than magic type?
I'm making it using echart and next+ ts
I checked that the magic type of E-chart is only line, bar, and stack. Can't you do something like a bar chart in a pie chart? Do I need to create a separate logic to make it like that?
The code is an e-chart dos example.
const option = {
  title: {
    text: 'Temperature Change in the Coming Week'
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis'
  },
  legend: {},
  toolbox: {
    show: true,
    feature: {
      dataZoom: {
        yAxisIndex: 'none'
      },
      dataView: { readOnly: false },
      magicType: { type: ['line', 'bar'] },
      restore: {},
      saveAsImage: {}
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: false,
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    axisLabel: {
      formatter: '{value} °C'
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Highest',
      type: 'line',
      data: [10, 11, 13, 11, 12, 12, 9],
      markPoint: {
        data: [
          { type: 'max', name: 'Max' },
          { type: 'min', name: 'Min' }
        ]
      },
      markLine: {
        data: [{ type: 'average', name: 'Avg' }]
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Lowest',
      type: 'line',
      data: [1, -2, 2, 5, 3, 2, 0],
      markPoint: {
        data: [{ name: '周最低', value: -2, xAxis: 1, yAxis: -1.5 }]
      },
      markLine: {
        data: [
          { type: 'average', name: 'Avg' },
          [
            {
              symbol: 'none',
              x: '90%',
              yAxis: 'max'
            },
            {
              symbol: 'circle',
              label: {
                position: 'start',
                formatter: 'Max'
              },
              type: 'max',
              name: '最高点'
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};


My opinion, you can only define two opitons to init the echarts in different condition
let pieChartTypeStr = 'pie' // maybe from a button 
echarts.init(document.getElementById("myChart")).clear();
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById("myChart"));
//pie option
var pieOption = {
    label:{
        fontSize:14,
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'pie-chart',
            type: 'pie',
            data: dataList,
        }
    ]
};
//bar option
var barOption = {
    xAxis: [
        {
            type: 'category',
            data: nameList,
        }
    ],
    yAxis: [
        {
            type: 'value'
        }
    ],
    series: [
        {
            name: 'value',
            type: 'bar',
            data: valueList
        }
    ]
};

if(pieChartTypeStr == 'pie') {
    myChart .setOption(pieOption);
}else {
    myChart .setOption(barOption);
}

